# Where is the equivalent of std::filesystem::last_write_time() for the file's creation time?

Tags: c++, file, filesystems, c++17, std

I'm using [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) and [`std::filesystem::last_write_time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/last_write_time) already, but now I also need the file **creation** time, and there doesn't seem to be an API for that in `std::filesystem`. Did I miss it? If not, how come there isn't one?

Do I have to resort to non-portable code to extract that creation timestamp? Does Boost. File system, the ancestor of `std::filesystem`, have such an API?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think it exists in C++17.

Boost contains [`boost::filesystem::creation_time`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#creation_time) since [version 1.75.0](https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_75_0.html) (December 2020). If you don't want to depend on Boost and only care about some platforms, you could use [their implementation](https://github.com/boostorg/filesystem/commit/1eec6f443d1fb1c17a05822caa10eba87635f897) for inspiration.

Note that creation time is inherently non-portable; although some filesystems do record creation times, [POSIX doesn't specify it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91200/177652). Whether this is the reason why C++17 doesn't implement it is anyone's guess.

Comment: BTW, on second thought, the fact not all filesystems record the creation time doesn't prevent having an API returning an std::optional, available in the same C++17 as std::filesystem itself, or return an error-code like Boost.Filesystem. I guess the fact POSIX does not have an API to access it was enough to sway the decision towards not having it, despite Windows and some Linux FS (like Ext4, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/7563) actually storing it.

Comment: On the other hand, POSIX does specify two other timestamps (last access time a.k.a. `atime`, and last status change time a.k.a. `ctime`) which are also missing from the C++17 stdlib. Maybe these had portability issues on non-POSIX platforms. Or maybe... they just took whatever happened to be implemented in Boost and called it done.